# Nested ANOVA with time data

Tags: r, time, statistics, anova

I am trying to perform a nested ANOVA including two factors.
Essentially, I have a time variable, which has been measured every week along one year. I want to explore differences among seasons and months, therefore I have assigned three different months to the four seasons (`seasons(months)=Winter(Jan, Feb, March), Spring(April, May, June), Summer(July, Sept), Autumn(Oct, Nov, Dec)`), resulting in a nested unbalanced design.

```
>modello<-lm(formula=y~season+season:month)
> anova(modello)

Analysis of Variance Table

Response: y
              Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
season         3 178811   59604 144.216 < 2.2e-16 ***
season:month   7  41335    5905  14.287 < 2.2e-16 ***
Residuals    493 203754     413                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

However, the df of the season:month does not seem to be correct: the df formula for a nested ANOVA is A(B-1), which in my case is 4(11-1). I also performed a Tukey test, but most of the results were NA:

```
$season
                   diff        lwr        upr p adj
Spring-Autumn  32.93056  26.453002  39.408109 0e+00
Summer-Autumn  15.14239   8.303663  21.981119 1e-07
Winter-Autumn -16.66300 -23.360587  -9.965413 0e+00
Summer-Spring -17.78816 -24.342077 -11.234252 0e+00
Winter-Spring -49.59356 -56.000055 -43.187056 0e+00
Winter-Summer -31.80539 -38.576856 -25.033926 0e+00

$`season:month`
                                         diff        lwr         upr     p adj
Spring:April-Autumn:April                  NA         NA          NA        NA
Summer:April-Autumn:April                  NA         NA          NA        NA
Winter:April-Autumn:April                  NA         NA          NA        NA
Autumn:December-Autumn:April               NA         NA          NA        NA
```

...

which would be the correct procedure?
Thank you in advance for help

Ennio

Comment: Are `season` and `month` both classified as factors?

Comment: Yes, both seasons and months were transformed as factors.